# Selecting a div before a "checkmark:checked" condition in CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-selectors

Okay, so I'm making a responsive navigation out of pure CSS (using a tutorial).  The way it works is, when you're viewing the responsive (condensed) menu, the "Menu" button has a hidden checkbox input assigned to it.  When the checkbox is checked, the navigation ul#menu (set to display:none; in mobile view) gets set to display:block like so:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {display:block;}
```

I also have a span with an arrow icon for menu items with submenus that rotates to point down when you hover over the li with the submenu.

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Link with Submenu</a><span class="arrow">></span></li>
.dropdown:hover .nav-arrow {transform:rotate(90deg);}
```

Standard stuff.

I didn't like the "hover" attribute displaying the submenu in mobile view, so I converted those to checkboxes as well.  So tapping the li items will trigger their own checkboxes to display the submenu ul beneath them.

```
input[type=checkbox]#show-menu:checked ~ .sub-nav {display:block;}
```

The problem I can't seem to figure out now is how to get the submenu arrows to rotate down when you tap(check) the submenu link.

I've tried moving the input both above and below the li with the arrow (using both checkbox:checked + .nav-arrow and checkbox:checked ~ .nav-arrow respectively), but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to appropriately select the span with the arrow after the checkbox is checked?  Appreciate it!

As a quick side note, I'm not JavaScript/jQuery savvy, and the point of this is to avoid using it, so any solutions negating those languages would be preferred. :)

Edit: Here's a js fiddle of my exact html/cs setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/nL3cd9mg/

Thanks for your responses so far, I hope the fiddle helps. :P

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a sample of the code you have used so far or make a js.fiddle of some kind so people can better help you.

Comment: Checkout http://bates.edu and the submenus at a mobile-sized view. Sounds like what you're trying to acheive.

Comment: Thanks, crazymatt!  I've edited with a jsfiddle.  And thanks, JakeParis, it is, visually, the effect I am going for, but they're doing it with javascript and I'm trying to avoid having to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Ah!  I finally got it.  Simple solution I overlooked, as always.  I just became more specific with my selectors:

```
input[type=checkbox]#show-cl-menu:checked ~ .show-cl-menu .nav-arrow {
```

instead of the old

`input[type=checkbox]#show-cl-menu:checked ~ .nav-arrow` {

Thanks everyone for your input!

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the actual rotation animation, try something like:

```
.subnav {
   transition: transform .5s;
}

input[type=checkbox]#show-menu:checked ~ .sub-nav {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Obviously you'll need to change precisly what that is applied to fit your exact situation. Your question has no html so I can't be more specific to your situation. But you can see the parts that work together to get that rotating arrow effect.